# Trying to use MKPointAnnotation title format in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

The default implementation of MKPointAnnotation shows titles beneath the pins, if desired:

[image]

I implemented viewFor Annotation in order to use a custom image, this eliminates MKPointAnnotation's title feature.

[image]

This code lives inside the networking code in the viewDidLoad in my MapViewController and pulls the location data from the shared instance array of location objects to create corresponding instances of my CustomAnnotation class:

```
// Create the annotations
    var tempArray = [CustomAnnotation]()

    for dictionary in Location.sharedInstance {

        let lat = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary.latitude)
        let long = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary.longitude)
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let name = dictionary.name
        let annotation = CustomAnnotation(coordinates: coordinates, title: name)
        tempArray.append(annotation)

    }

// Add the annotations to the annotations array
        self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.annotationArray)
        self.annotationArray = tempArray
        self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.annotationArray)
   }
```

This is my CustomAnnotation class:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    var title: String?

    init(coordinates location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
        super.init()

        self.coordinate = location
        self.title = title

    }
}
```

And this is my viewFor implementation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

    if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
        annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    else {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView {

        for location in Location.sharedInstance {
            if annotationView.annotation?.coordinate.latitude == location.latitude && annotationView.annotation?.coordinate.longitude == location.longitude {
                if location.rating < 2 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "1star")
                } else if location.rating == 2 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "2star")
                } else if location.rating == 2.5 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "2star")
                } else if location.rating == 3.0 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "3star")
                } else if location.rating == 3.5 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "3star")
                } else if location.rating == 4.0 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "4star")
                } else if location.rating == 4.5 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "4star")
                } else if location.rating > 4.5 {
                    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "5star")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Is there a simple way of porting MKPointAnnotation's title format or do I have to make a custom view? Perhaps as importantly, is it safe to assume I would need to write some logic to prevent titles from closely located pins from being a jumble of text? Apple's MKPointAnnotation seems to have this logic built in, in that it just declines to show many titles.

Comment: add your custom annotation relevant code,

Comment: @reinier can you be more specific?

Comment: Add what your have done so far

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok check it out. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks for your help